# Firebase + Flutter: can't lock access to unverified email accounts

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'd like to block out people who didn't verify their email so i figured out this code for sign up:

```js
// sign up

  Future signUp(String email, String password) async {
    

    try {
      await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
    } catch (e) {
      print('An error has occured by creating a new user');
      print(
        e.toString(),
      );
    }

    try {
      final FirebaseUser _user = await _auth.currentUser();
      await _user.sendEmailVerification();
    } catch (error) {
      print("An error occured while trying to send email verification");
      print(error.toString());
    }
    try {
      await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }
```

and this for sign in:

```js
//Sign In with Email and Pass

  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {

FirebaseUser _user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

if (_user != null && _user.isEmailVerified == true) {
  try {
    await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    return _user;
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
} else {
  return null;
}
  }
```

_auth is just an instance of FirebaseAuth.
The problem is that i can login even if i didnt verify the email.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Auth doesn't stop accounts from signing in if the user hasn't verified their email address yet.  You can check that property `_user.isEmailVerified` to find out the state of that validation after the user signs in, and you can determine from there what the user should see.

Comment: But why doesn't my code work if I check isEmailVerified like this ?

Comment: Because it's checking *before* sign-in, not *after* sign-in. As I said, you can't stop the sign-in based on validation state.

Comment: So what should I do exactly ?

Comment: As I said in the answer:  You can check that property _user.isEmailVerified to find out the state of that validation **after** the user signs in, and you can determine from there what the user should see.

Comment: I saw a video of guy that did it usign Android but I don't understand how https://youtu.be/06YKlMdWyMM

Comment: The APIs between Flutter and Android are nearly identical.  Whatever you're trying to do should be the same procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'll check it bit by bit

Answer (score 1):

`isEmailVerified` can be a little bit of trouble to get working correctly.
Make sure you are calling

```
 await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()..reload();
```

before your are calling `isEmailVerified` also in my own experience and I don't know if this is just something I was doing wrong but this did not work from my `Auth` class this did not start working until I put the code directly in `initState()` of my widget that checks whether the user is verified. Like I said that part might have been something I did wrong. Like stated this will not listen for change you must check yourself either periodically or at a point that you know email is verified.

```
Future(() async {
      _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) async {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()
          ..reload();
        var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
        if (user.isEmailVerified) {
          timer.cancel();
          Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(HearingsScreen.routeName);
        }
      });
    });
```

So it checks every 10 seconds to see if the user has verified their email not the most elegant solution. The page I have this on just displays a message  'Please verify your email' so its not like this is interrupting other code. If your app is performing other tasks this might not be an option for you. If you want to play around with `isEmailVerified` go ahead but i spent a week of headaches until i settled on this.

Comment: What should I put in InitState() exactly ?

Comment: I will post how I did it the problem is once the user is presented with a page that says you are not authenticated please verify your email. We as programmers do not know when to check ``isEmailVerified`` again the user might go verify their email immediately or they may not verify their email for a week(firebases email will expire before then but you get the problem?)

Comment: did this help you